# Forward with query in express js

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I tried to forward some requests to another handler:

```
route.get("/tag/:id",function(req,res,next){
  req.url="/posts?tag_id="+req.params.id
  next('route')
})

route.get("/posts",function(req,res,next){
  console.info(req.query);
})
```

The `query` is empty in the second handler.

How to fix that?

Comment: why do you want that ? First alternative, use `res.redirect()`, second to write logic else where and consume it in routers.

Comment: @MukeshSharma Exatcly. Redirection makes more sense in these cases.

Comment: Think about the permalink link in wordpress, you can not redirect the `/tag/x` to `index.php?tag_name=x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`req.query` is empty because you set the url manually and it doesn't get parsed again.

It the second handler is called but only the `req.query` is not set, then instead of:

```
route.get("/tag/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = "/posts?tag_id=" + req.params.id;
  next('route');
});
```

you can try:

```
route.get("/tag/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = "/posts?tag_id=" + req.params.id;
  req.query = {tag_id: req.params.id}; // or whatever you want
  next('route');
});
```

or:

```
route.get("/tag/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = "/posts?tag_id=" + req.params.id;
  req.query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  next('route');
});
```

If it is used in your handlers then you may also need to update `req.params`, `req.path` and [other request properties](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req).

Comment: Instead I use `req.query = url.parse(req.url, true).query`, thank you.